# Can I replace one with the other? L7805CP, L7805CV

Tags: repair, replacement

[image]

Are those chip equal in a circuit?

L7805CP,   L7805CV

Can I replace one with the other to try to fix a broken circuit board?

Comment: Read the fantastic data sheets for both. However, that does not guarantee that they will be exactly equal in a circuit. The devil's in the detail.

Comment: My tummy tells me the right one is a counterfeit. I've never seen big-brand semiconductor packages have silkscreen that's not properly aligned. Why should that ever happen in a running high-volume high-speed packaging line?

Comment: @Marcus: Wonky text does not make a component counterfeit. I've seen plenty - even ones which are almost unreadable.  Perhaps I've just looked at more components than you have.

Comment: @JasonM that is indeed pretty likely. To be fair, ST sent me samples of a QSOP IC once, where the pins on one of four sides were mounted upside down. Tech support was just "oh, no guarantees for samples, kthxbay" when I tried to tell them that there's something wrong in their production. *visibly shrugs*

Comment: Just FYI for repairing old gadgets with 7805s, if there's a significant load on them, you can consider drop in switching 7805 replacements for higher efficiency.  They're a couple bucks each, but it's generally a big improvement and plug and play to boot.  If the load on the old 7805 is really small don't bother though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in packaging.  The L7805CP on the left is an all plastic package.  the L7805CV, on the right, has a metal tab.

As long as your application doesn't depend on the ground connection on the metal tab, it should work.

Comment: minor thing: the all-plastic package (CP) has 60 K/W thermal resistance, the "normal" TO-220 (CV) only 50 K/W. This won't be a difference, since the CV shows no sign of having been screwed or pressed onto a heat sink, so waste heat probably won't be critical.

Comment: The square corner passivation seems to show a heatsink clamp was used with unequal pressure

Comment: Thank you guys very much for responding, I know this was a bad question and probably not valid for this site